# The message sent by twilio is sent as "likely-SCAM" without a mask

Tags: node.js, twilio, sms

I can't see the masked "myApp" name and the name appears as "likely-SCAM". Even if I send sms without a mask, the same issue remains. Can you help to resolve this issue? sms sending part is working fine

I used the following code

````
// Set up Twilio client
const accountSid = 'YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID';
const authToken = 'YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN';
const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

async function maskPhoneNumberAndSendMessage(phoneNumber, visiblePhoneNumber, message) {
  try {
    // Create a Twilio incoming phone number
    const incomingPhoneNumber = await client.incomingPhoneNumbers.create({
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      friendlyName: visiblePhoneNumber,
    });

    // Retrieve the masked phone number
    const maskedPhoneNumber = incomingPhoneNumber.phoneNumber;

    // Send a message using the masked phone number
    const sentMessage = await client.messages.create({
      body: message,
      from: maskedPhoneNumber,
      to: 'RECIPIENT_PHONE_NUMBER',
    });

    // Return the sent message details
    return sentMessage;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

const phoneNumberToMask = '+1234567890';
const visiblePhoneNumber = 'myApp';
const messageToSend = 'Hello, this is a masked message from Twilio!';

maskPhoneNumberAndSendMessage(phoneNumberToMask, visiblePhoneNumber, messageToSend)
  .then((sentMessage) => {
    console.log('Sent Message SID:', sentMessage.sid);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  });```
````

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this, you will need to register your Twilio phone numbers with at least the [Free Caller Registry](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/9375068873499-Outbound-Calls-Blocked-or-Labeled-as-Spam-or-Scam-Likely) and possibly with other registers directly such as [First Orion](https://portal.firstorion.com/app/landing/#/signup). Registering with these services almost immediately removes the blocking and nuisance labelling. So long as you can meet the requirements and complete the verification process.

In addition, you should review and complete the [A2P 10DLC requirements](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260800720410-What-is-A2P-10DLC-) on the Twilio site. Doing the A2P 10DLC registration with Twilio will not automatically register your number/campaign with Free Caller Registry - you need to do both. While you have gone this far you should also complete the [Trusted Calling with SHAKEN/STIR](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/trusted-calling-with-shakenstir).

Also, Twilio has an excellent page "[Outbound Calls Blocked or Labeled as Spam or Scam Likely](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/9375068873499-Outbound-Calls-Blocked-or-Labeled-as-Spam-or-Scam-Likely)" which describes what to do if your calls are labelled as SPAM. I'd suggest making this part of your new number provisioning process. Otherwise, your calls and texts will be blocked by nomorobo and the like.

The reason why I started off with "as of writing this" as these requirements seem to be a moving target. I know you asked about SMS but, in my experience, I needed to do the above to allow outbound voice and SMS to go through consistently.